# Installing validator on a tableModel qt

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to install validator (regex i.e) for a tableMOdel or some cells in this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any built in support for validation in the model/view system but this wouldn't be too difficult to do.

In [`QAbstractItemModel::setData`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) you will need to validate the input, and return false if invalid, store the result of validation somewhere.

In [[`QAbstractItemModel::data`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) you could now return a different colour for the `Qt::BackgroundRole` role to signal something was wrong.

In addition, you could implement a custom [`QAbstractItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemdelegate.html) this would allow you to create a validating editor, which could provide more feedback to the user.

The delegate would then be set on the view with one of the [`QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) or `setItemDelegateFor*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is set a custom delegate for painting a specific column, this delegate should paint a widget of choice, and on this widget set a validator using setValidator(...)

The validator could be a custom validator (class inheriting from QValidator) or one of the existing.

Check this link for a good description on setting the custom item delegate.
http://qtwiki.org/Creating_QTableView_TextEditDelegate

And this for the validator
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39310-Some-QComboBox-and-custom-QValidator-background